# Command line doesn't use python from conda environment even though it's active, maybe problem in .bash_profile?

Tags: python, macos, conda, miniconda

I've activated a conda environment and see it's active, but when I type "which python", I get `"/usr/local/bin/python"`, instead of the python of the environment. And I get Import errors for packages I know are installed. I think the problem might be in `.bash_profile`, but I don't know how to fix it.

I'm working on macOS.

How do I make sure that the command line uses the environment's python?

Comment: What does PATH env variable contains ? Probably `export PATH="/path/to/conda/bin:$PATH"` in your bashrc would help but probably also better to run `conda init bash`. It will do anything you need to use conda properly.

Comment: I added this as answer as you could accept it.

Comment: How did you install Conda?

Comment: I had the same issue. Turns out that I forgot to specify a python version during the initialization. Can be solved by `conda create --name snakes python=3.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PATH` environment variable probably doesn't contains the path to the python environment from conda.

Running `export PATH="/path/to/conda/bin:$PATH"` or adding it to your `~/.bashrc` would probably solve your issue.

But there is a conda command that does it for you: `conda init bash`

**EDIT**:

As mentionned in comment by @cel and also in the [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#conda-init) : It's better to use `conda init` than explicitely editing `PATH` by your own.

This will allow conda being less disruptive regarding other programs on your system.

`conda init` will add some more commands in your shell rc file to only modify `PATH` when a conda environment is activated.

Comment: Note that setting PATH works, but it is NOT recommended, instead use `conda init bash`.  They are not equivalent. See also: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#conda-init

Comment: It's what I said ... better to use `conda init` but thanks for down vote ! Did you ever had a look at what `conda init` do ? ;-)

Comment: The downvote is not against you personally, I just don't think this is a good answer at the moment. IMO it is not a good idea to mention setting the PATH - it is explicitly advised against that in the conda docs. Also `conda init` does not set the path like you do, it uses a special way to only make a conda command available in the shell, but not other executables which are in `<conda-env>/bin`. I would be more than happy to retract my downvote if you consider editing it to reflect this.

Comment: Not being a good answer don't mean being a bad one so I think it just deserve a comment to discuss before downvoting ! I edited my answer to add more information but I still think it's a good thing to talk about `PATH` because Python use this to know where it's interpreter is located so it would help to understand how it works !

Comment: @LoïcG. Talking about PATH is not a bad thing, I think what they take issue with is the fact that the bad solution is mentioned before the good one, and the importance of using `conda init` is buried at the end.